# Ordered Sequence of learning algorithm design techniques

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, backtracking, greedy

So, I am taking a algorithms course this semester.
I have a basic understanding of design techniques and know that **divide and conquer** should be the first technique t learn.
But coming to backtracking, dynamic programming and greedy techniques *I am confused to choose an appropriate order*

While my course is structured in the order i described in above paragraph.

Suggest me..

Comment: Look at the problem and try to find a similarity to a problem you already know. This will give you an idea which approach might work.

Comment: I guess you haven't got my issue. I need an order to learn the design techniques. Not while solving a problem.

Comment: I think `greedy` is the easiest to understand and also quite often used. Than I would go for backtracking and than for dynamic programming.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you will lose anything by simply following the order that your course suggests. I notice that [TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_and_analysis_of_algorithms/index.htm) presents in a different order, and adds several other techniques. I think you will gain a lot by simply working your way through such material.

It's likely that your learning style is different from mine, but I find it very beneficial to do a breadth-first survey of a topic, happily accepting that I won't understand every detail the first time round, then drill down as my understanding increases. So I don't feel the need for a detailed order of study.

Comment: Like your way of learning, but I feel overwhelmed when I have no basic prerequisites before starting a new topic.